# JSLintNet.MSBuild doesn't allow define constant field

Tags: javascript, c#, .net

I try define constant field in the js file like this `const someName= "some Value"`, project type is asp.net web application where I have installed JSLintNet.MSBuild NuGet and now I get an error:

.

```
/*global Hammer, YTDateRange, YTGridLabel, YTGridMilestone */
const scrollRatio = -120;

var YTGridPanel = new Class({
    Implements: [Events], Binds: ["update", "updatePanelGeometry", "pan",
            "redrawCanvas",
            "suspendZooming", "resumeZooming",
            "handleWindowResize", "onScroll",
            "onDblClick", "onMouseDown", "onMouseMove", "onMouseUp", "onPageScroll"],
...
)}
```

> JSLint : Unexpected 'const'.

Comment: https://github.com/benquarmby/jslintnet/issues/29 - note that package hasn't been updated for nearly 3 years

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add "esversion": 6 in your JSHint Options (.json file) and update NuGet packeg version to latest version.